# R - How to average every n row within ID with long data?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a large dataframe in long format that contains about 13k rows. It contains mostly numeric but some string variables. Here is example data of what it looks like.

```
id <- c(101,101,101,101,101,101,101,101,101,
        102,102,102,102,102,102,
        103,103,103,103,103,103,103,103,103,103,103)
color <- c("red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red",
           "blue","blue","blue","blue","blue","blue",
           "green","green","green","green","green","green","green","green","green","green","green")
time <- c(1:9, 1:6, 1:11) 
var1 <- sample(1:3, 26, replace=TRUE)
var2 <- sample(1:3, 26, replace=TRUE)
var3 <- sample(1:3, 26, replace=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(id,color,time,var1,var2,var3)
```

```
    id color time var1 var2 var3
1  101   red    1    1    1    3
2  101   red    2    1    3    1
3  101   red    3    1    3    1
4  101   red    4    1    3    3
5  101   red    5    2    2    3
6  101   red    6    1    1    2
7  101   red    7    1    3    1
8  101   red    8    1    2    1
9  101   red    9    1    2    2
10 102  blue    1    1    1    1
11 102  blue    2    1    3    2
12 102  blue    3    1    1    1
13 102  blue    4    3    2    1
14 102  blue    5    1    3    2
15 102  blue    6    2    1    1
16 103 green    1    3    1    3
17 103 green    2    2    3    2
18 103 green    3    2    3    1
19 103 green    4    1    1    3
20 103 green    5    2    3    2
21 103 green    6    3    3    2
22 103 green    7    3    2    3
23 103 green    8    3    1    2
24 103 green    9    3    1    2
25 103 green   10    3    2    1
26 103 green   11    1    2    1
```

I want to make this time-series dataframe smoother and average every n rows (e.g. every 3 rows) - averaging `time`, `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` within `id`, leaving id and color unaffected. The end result should have now have 1 row for every 3 original rows. However, the only solution I have thought of so far is to split the dataframe in a list of dataframes by `id`, and then use aggregate for each new dataframe, but this is impractical with my real data and causes the color variable to become `NA`. Other attempts cause errors because my chosen n doesn't always cleanly average the rows (e.g. trying to average every 3 rows when there are 11 total rows for `id` 103). Is there a more practical solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create a grouping column with `gl` along with 'id', 'color' and `summarise` `across` the columns that `starts_with` 'var'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id, color, grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 3, n()))) %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with('var'), mean), .groups = 'drop')
```